# Failed to load template in truffle project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, ethereum, truffle

[image]

I am developing Dapp using Truffle v3.1.2 which is a development framework for Ethereum.I am using angular on node for this dapp & unfortunately I am very new to node & webpack.I am storing views in /views folder, images in /images folder & I need some help to modify the webpack.config.js file.I am using “npm run dev” to deploy it & I am getting “Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/main.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)” message.Please find the webpack.config.js file below.

```html
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        './app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        './app/javascripts/app.js',],
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    // Copy our app's index.html to the build folder.
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './app/index.html', to: "index.html" }
    ])
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```